# Calculate the Bromwich Integral (Inverse Laplace Transform)

Tags: integral-transforms

How can I calculate the Bromwich Integral in Mathematica? If I enter this as code it gives me just the same:

$$\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{\alpha-\infty i}^{\alpha+\infty i} \left(e^{st}\cdot F_{(s)}\right) \text{d}s$$

As example:

I want to calculate the inverse laplace transform of $\frac{c}{s}$:

$$\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{\alpha-\infty i}^{\alpha+\infty i} \left(e^{st}\cdot \frac{c}{s}\right) \text{d}s$$

Than it gives me the same back, maybe I've to set some conditions to my code?

My code:

```
Integrate[Exp[s*t]*(c/s), {s, a - Infinity*I, a + Infinity*I}]/(2*Pi*I)
```

---

The Bromwich Integral: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/BromwichIntegral.html

Comment: `InverseLaplaceTransform[c/s, s, t]`?

Comment: That function don't give the conditions when the integral is equal to the answer, so I would like to calculate the integral, than it gives me a conditionalexpression

Comment: If you post the actual code it might be easier (i) to see if there is a mistake in it and (ii) for others to try it out, maybe try variations.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think one possible issue is that e.g. `a+Infinity*I` becomes just `DirectedInfinity[I]` because the "finite" part gets swallowed. You can rewrite in such a way that this does not happen.

```
Integrate[
 Exp[(s*I + a)*t]*(1/(s*I + a)), {s, - Infinity, Infinity}, 
 Assumptions -> Element[{a, t}, Reals]]

(* Out[246]= ConditionalExpression[
 E^(a t) (\[Pi] (Cosh[a Abs[t]] Sign[t] - Sinh[a Abs[t]]) + 
    I CosIntegral[-I a Abs[t]] (Cosh[a Abs[t]] - 
       Sign[t] Sinh[a Abs[t]]) + 
    I CosIntegral[
      I a Abs[t]] (-Cosh[a Abs[t]] + Sign[t] Sinh[a Abs[t]])), a != 0] *)
```

Comment: Much better than mine! With the `Assumptions` that `a > 0` and `t >= 0`, this returns *exactly* `2*Pi`.  Doing the same thing for the second example in my answer also returns exactly the correct answer.  +1

Comment: But it gives not what I expected, because the laplace inverse of $\frac{c}{s}$ is equal to $c$, and I whout like to find the conditions when it becomes $c$

Comment: @JanEerland. Okay, conditions on `c`? You can put `c` back into the expression that he is integrating, and it will spit out no extra condition because `c` can be anything in your simple case. More generally, if you use this method, and *if* MMA can do the integral, then it will spit out conditions on whatever constants are in your integrand. You should still specify conditions on `a` and `t` in your integral, however, because that is necessary for the definition of the inverse Laplace transform.

Comment: @march I actually liked your result more. I just wanted to post something that did not require limits or related.

Comment: I'm not sure either solution will end up being very robust. I'm still convinced that `InverseLaplaceTransform` is best, since it will have the giant look-up table of Laplace-transform pairs, and the OP can look up somewhere what the conditions on the functions are. (I'm still not entirely sure what the OP wants, anyway.) Nonetheless, I found your solution to be clever.

Answer (score 7):

This is decidedly not a general answer, but let's play a bit. If we do

```
expr = Integrate[Exp[s t] c/s
  , {s, a - b I, a + b I}
  , Assumptions -> {a > 0, b > a, c ∈ Reals, t ∈ Reals}]/(2*π*I)
```

this yields

```
ConditionalExpression[
 -((I c (-ExpIntegralEi[(a - I b) t] + ExpIntegralEi[(a + I b) t]))/(2 π))
 , t >= 0]
```

We of course need to choose `a > 0` because the vertical contour that we integrate along needs to be to the right of any poles in the function we are integrating. In this case, there is a pole at 0. I am using `b > a > 0` because I find it doubtful that *Mathematica* knows how to integrate the thing along the entire vertical contour: in fact, if you try it, *Mathematica* says that the integral does not converge (which is not surprising! - we are in some sense trying to compute a principle value integral). Finally, of course `t` needs to be non-negative. We knew this already from the definitions of the Laplace transform and inverse Laplace transform.

In any case, we can now set `a` to anything positive we want, so let's consider the following:

```
Limit[expr /. {a -> 1, t -> #}] & /@ {1, 5, 0.4, 100}
(* {c, c, 1. c, c} *)
```

which of course suggests that the expression is equal to `c`.

In general, *if* the integral of your function `f[s]` can actually be evaluated, then I would do

```
Integrate[Exp[s t] f[s]
  , {s, a - b I, a + b I}
  , Assumptions -> {a > 0, b > a, t >= 0}]/(2*π*I)
```

and play around with the results. I do not think this will work very often, however. In addition, if it does spit back a solution, the functions that it yields are likely to have branch cuts that you have to worry about. I think that symbolic complex integration with computers is hard.

---

If you try

```
Integrate[1/(2 \[Pi] I) Exp[s t] 1/(1 + s^2), {s, a - b I, a + b I}, Assumptions -> {a > 0, b > a, t >= 0}]
```

you get back something with `Gamma` functions and `Log` functions evaluated at imaginary inputs. If you let `a -> 2` and try taking the `Limit` as `b -> Infinity` with integer of `t`, eventually you get an expression that will `ExpToTrig` to `Sin[t]` while spitting out errors that you might need to be concerned about. (Nonetheless, that's the right answer).